# Returning from method inside a @synchronized block

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I'd just like to know if it's advised to `return` from a method within a `@synchronized` block? For example:

```
- (id)test {
   @synchronized(self) {
      if (a) return @"A";
      else return @"B";
   }
}
```

As opposed to:

```
- (id)test {
   NSString *value;
   @synchronized(self) {
      if (a) value = @"A";
      else value = @"B";
   }
   return value;
}
```

This sample is rather simplistic, but sometimes in a complex method it would make things simpler to be able to return from within a `@synchronized` block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's fine. `@synchronized` is aware of the `return` statement.

(Ref: <strike>http://www.thaesofereode.info/clocFAQ/#sync-advs</strike>) - *dead link*
(Ref: http://nextstep.sdf-eu.org/clocFAQ/#sync-advs) - *this link reference above dead one and may not be up to date as its header says*