# return from inside a @synchronized block in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, synchronized

May somebody tell me if it is ok to return from inside a `@synchronized` block?

For example:

```
    - (id)methodThatReturnsSomething:(BOOL)bDoIt
    {
        @synchronized(self) {      

             if(!bDoIt) return nil;
             ...
        }
    }
```

or should I unlock the block first (using NSLock instead)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning from method inside a @synchronized block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704400/returning-from-method-inside-a-synchronized-block)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`@synchronized` will automatically take down its exception-handling context when you return, and relinquish the lock. So the code you've written is fine.

Comment: +1 It's worth mentioning that this is pretty much *why* `@synchronized` exists – it relieves of you having to manually relinquish any locks of your own (which can get quite spaghetti-like with multiple code paths).

Comment: Answer with 27 votes from a no longer existing user is nice however would be nice to have the links to some authoritative sources.