# Using @synchronized in a method with a return value

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

If I am using the directive @synchronized in a method, and the method has a return value BOOL or NSString, which do I use?

```
@synchronized(self)  {
    if (![self hasSource]) {
        *source = nil;
        return YES;
    } 


}
return NO;
```

=== OR ====

```
@synchronized(self)  {
    if (![self hasSource]) {
        *source = nil;
        return YES;
    } 

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning from method inside a @synchronized block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704400/returning-from-method-inside-a-synchronized-block)

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri That duplicate question is similar but the answer doesn't really help with this question. It doesn't explain why or when to use one form or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you posted, either works since the return value can't be affected by two threads trying to access the synchronized code at the same time.

You would want the `return` in the synchronized block if the return value could be affected by another thread.

Answer (score 1):

OK I don't know for sure, but in my mind I would think the former example as then the entire operation is protected by the @synchronize directive.

Certainly I would, without the doubt now seeded in my mind, code it that way.